# How can I dynamically change the target directory in spec file of pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, specifications

I'm trying to distribute the executable of the python code using pyinstaller.
I'm wonder whether there is a way to change directory dynamically depending on the target platform.

For example, if executable is 32bit, target dir is AAAx32, if 64bit, target dir is AAAx64 in my spec file.

```
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           name='AAA')     # <-- Change this dynamically.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try** os and platform

```
import platform
import os
platform.system()
>'Windows'

platform.machine()
>'AMD64'
```

For further information, please [read](https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild/wiki/OS_flavor_name_version) this.